# puppet facter mac model

Tags: macos, puppet

I'm creating a puppet manifest and I'm trying to use a built in facter variable based on the MAC model. I'm using this guide: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/3.1/core_facts.html

I saw `system_profiler` with an option for `model_identifier` but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

Here is where I'm confused:

```
class::something::mac
if $<% system_profiler %> eq "macpro"; then
do the thing
else
don't do the thing
```

Where/how do I actually use model_identifier? I'm new to puppet and MAC so any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

My current facter version v2.4 doesn't support it, but I can't successfully install latest facter v3.1.4, so can't test the code. It should be closed for your question.

```
if $::system_profiler::model_identifier == "MacBookPro10,2" {
   do the thing
}
else {
   don't do the thing
}
```

Run the command on your mac to prove it.

```
$ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro10,2
```

Related codes at:

```
+            { "Model Identifier",       [](data& d) -> string& { return d.model_identifier; } },
```

https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/commit/4283cfe23b56f22b03fbc863a3eb1498d2bcbea9#diff-c8b70e57e1ae5727ed062f26d5a9fa30R25

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I use sp_machine_model? `if $sp_machine_model == "MacBookPro10,2" { do the thing } else { don't do the thing }`

Comment: looks fine for me, or `$::sp_machine_model`

Comment: I'll try that out! Thank you.